# REBOL Program simple GUI window , starting

Tags: rebol

i have downloaded REBOL.

Want to start some little GUI windows.

Have saved many READY  sample code as R  file in my folder.

Now i have tried to start theese GUI codes.

But there is always the same error message .  no value

** Script Error: view has no value
** Script Error: layout has no value

There must be a value for the view  or layout window.

But the code examples are READY. How can this happen ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Rebol are you using, and where did you download it from?  What are the code samples you are trying to run, and what version of Rebol were they written for?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have downloaded Rebol/Core. For the graphical goodies, please download Rebol/View.

If you are just playing at this stage, go for Rebol 2 rather than the experimental and incomplete Rebol 3 variants.

Rebol 2 View is available here:

http://www.rebol.com/download-view.html